# Excel OpenXML Set Row as ReadOnly

Tags: excel, ms-office, openxml

I have a requirement to make the header row(row containing the headers in my excel document) read-only and also minimize it's height as much as possible so it is barely visible. How do I do this either in excel itself or via code?

Note: header row is not the first row of my excel document. In fact there are 7 of them(rows) and I would like to prevent use from modifying any of the data in the cells.

Comment: Try `sheet protection` and `locking the header row cells` for `read-only`. Try changing the `Row Height` for making it `barely visible`. All can be in XL itself, with no use for code.

Comment: Would sheet protection not lock all of the rows in the sheet?

Comment: Would sheet protection not lock all of the rows in the sheet? That seems to be what is happening. I selected the particular row I wanted to set as read-only, and specified this in the properties section. then I set protect sheet, and I could no longer type data into any other cell in that sheet afterwards.

Comment: you need to only lock the cells in the header row that you want to be "read-only" leave all the other cells as un-locked and do not allow user to select locked cells. Everything else, presumably they can do. By default cells are locked. you have to go in and unlock them.

Comment: how do I lock the cells, I am guessing you mean I need to do them individually.

Comment: Not sure which version of XL you are on, but if you open the Format Cells Dialog Box, then go to the Protection tab, you can click the Locked check box. You can do this on just one cell or you can highlight a range of cells (or full rows or columns ... or multiple rows / columns). In your case, select every row except your header and then do what I wrote above.

Comment: I am using Office 2010. I am doing most what you are saying to here and I still can't seem to just protect/lock only the rows that I would like to lock. What ends up happening is that the whole sheet is locked and this is not what I want.

Comment: can you post your workbook.. or a sample workbook through a link?